# Different results when oppening a binary .ply file with ifstream under windows and linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ifstream

I am trying to read a `.ply` file with c++ and save the geometric information in vectors (The border points are `floats` and the border triangles are `int's`. The code works under Linux but when I try to use it under Windows it doesn't behave as intended.

Here is a trimmed down version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string FilenamePLY;

int NumberBorderPoint = 1572866;
int BorderNumberTriangle = 3145728;

char numFloat;
char numInt;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FilenamePLY = "file_test.ply";

    ifstream fin(FilenamePLY.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberBorderPoint; i++){
            fin.read(&numFloat, sizeof(float));
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                fin.read(&numFloat, sizeof(float));
            }

    }
    cout << fin.gcount() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i<BorderNumberTriangle; i++){
            fin.read(&numInt, sizeof(int));
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)   {
                fin.read(&numInt, sizeof(int));
            }
    }
    cout << fin.gcount() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiled and executed under Windows outputs:

```
0
0
```

Whereas under Linux the output is:

```
4
4
```

My feeling is that the read function doesn't get the correct values to separate the numbers in the binary files but `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(int)` both have the same value under Windows  and Linux (4).

Any ideas of where the problem lies ?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: You have no error trapping.  Did you debug and test for an error opening the file?

Comment: Could you show an example of the input file being read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open the file for **binary** reading:

```
ifstream fin(FilenamePLY.c_str(), std::ios::binary );
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the file in binary mode and verify you opened the file.

You are also currently reading data of sizeof(float) into a character - its going to overwrite other data at that point (numFloat, numInt)